# Aws codecommit branch access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codecommit

Good afternoon,

Im searching for hours and didnt find anything, its possible to disable some users to push on master in AWS Codecommit?

Best regards,
Fellipe M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the 16th of May 2018 AWS announced "CodeCommit now enables you to restrict who can commit changes to the master branch or any branch of your choosing"

You will need to create a IAM policy and attach it to the restricted group or user. Below is the example IAM policy. Update "Resource" with the desired arn or *

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": [
            "codecommit:GitPush",
            "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
            "codecommit:PutFile",
            "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-2:80398EXAMPLE:MyDemoRepo",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                "codecommit:References": [
                    "refs/heads/master"   
                ]
            },
            "Null": {
                "codecommit:References": false
            }
        }
    }
]
```

}

Below is the link to the original blog post https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/refining-access-to-branches-in-aws-codecommit/

Comment: Works. Thank you very much

Comment: Please note that `Deny` "codecommit:DeleteBranch" only protects branches to be deleted using UI. you can still delete using `git push -d origin <branch_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently branch level permissions are not available in AWS CodeCommit.

Comment: Now they do https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/05/aws-codecommit-supports-branch-level-permissions/ !!

Comment: Yes they can. Here is the policy you can create. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-conditional-branch.html